# Use coption Metaplex Beet

Tags: metaplex

I have a misunderstanding and I need your help. I use Metaplex Beet to deserialize data. I'm trying to manage the case of optional data. For that I use COption on my type and the coption() method in my field. No specific error at this level.
[image: COption type]

[image: coption method]

Then I call a method with several arguments, one of which is of type: GlobalBeetStruct which allows me to have access to the .deserialize() method

I want console.log() my progress, and I run a unit test and it is at this level that I have an error:
[image: Error from coption]

Do you have an idea?